# How to terminate Correctly thread on application exit

Tags: python, .net, multithreading, winforms, python.net

I am making simple gui using pythonnet.

```
import os, sys, ntpath, threading
from subprocess import call

import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")


import System
import System.Windows.Forms as WinForms
from System.Threading import ApartmentState, Thread, ThreadStart
from System.Windows.Forms import (Application, Form, Button)
from System.Drawing import Point

class demo(WinForms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = None
        self.InitializeComponent()

    def InitializeComponent(self):
        """Initialize form components."""
        self.components = System.ComponentModel.Container()
        self.btn = Button()
        self.btn.Parent = self
        self.btn.Click += self.process
        self.CenterToScreen()
        self.cmd = "Running forever command"

    def Dispose(self):
        self.components.Dispose()
        WinForms.Form.Dispose(self)

    def thread_process(self):
        call(self.cmd, shell=True)
        pass

    def process(self, sender, args):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_process, daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()

    def OnClickFileExit(self, sender, args):
        self.Close()

WinForms.Application.Run(demo())
```

It works fine but when I click Exit button, Obviously the application doesn't stop. How to correctly stop the running thread when user closes the application?

Comment: Is this IronPython or pythonnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try setting your `process` thread as `deamon` thread if it suits your need:

```
self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_process, daemon=True)
```

Here's some info on the deamon threads:

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
> flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
> are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The
> flag can be set through the daemon property.
>
> Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Comment: Already did. I think the problem is subprocess.call which starts another non-daemon.

Comment: Solved. But The Problem started when the resulting programme was another python thread. So it mixed all up.